# Converting repeating code into a loop for easier management using powershell and a json file

Tags: json, powershell

I am coding in powershell. I have a json file that I convert to a powershell object. I have more than 30 settings (key, value) I need to check to either update or add.  What would be a better way of turning the following code into a loop of some kind so that I don't have to code each individual setting and future additional setting will be easy to update?  I was thinking a hashtable with the keys and values and a foreach loop but all my attempts have failed.  I don't know enough about hashtables to be able to manipulate the foreach loop the way I'm thinking.  Or if that's even the best path to attempt this with.

JSON File:

```
{
  "editor.tabSize": 4,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false
}
```

Code:

```
$Json = Get-Content 'C:\settings.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

# Will update an existing keys value since the object already has that key
$EditorTabSize = 2
# Does key exist in the object
if ($Json.'editor.tabSize' -ne $null) {
    # Does key have the correct value
    if ($Json.'editor.tabSize' -ne $EditorTabSize) {
        # Change keys value
        $Json.'editor.tabSize' = $EditorTabSize
    }     
}
else {
    # Add key and value to object
    $Json | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'editor.tabSize' -Value $EditorTabSize
}

# Will add a new key and value since the object does not have that key yet
$WorkbenchStartupEditor = "newUntitledFile"
if ($Json.'workbench.startupEditor' -ne $null) {
    if ($Json.'workbench.startupEditor' -ne $WorkbenchStartupEditor) {
        $Json.'workbench.startupEditor' = $WorkbenchStartupEditor
    }     
}
else {
    $Json | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'workbench.startupEditor' -Value $WorkbenchStartupEditor
}

# Convert object back into json format
$JsonOutput = ConvertTo-Json $json
```

Some other setting I need to code for:

```
"git.autofetch": true,
"editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
"editor.trimAutoWhitespace": true,
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
"extensions.showRecommendationsOnlyOnDemand": true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided contained just about everything you needed the solve the problem, and I applaud your efforts.  In fact, even your suggestion on how to solve it was spot-on.

In the solution below, I've simply created an array (`$desired`) containing key-value pairs, which I then iterate over and apply those values to the `$Json` object using your original code.

To extend it, you can easily add your own elements to the `$desired` array.

It may be worth mentioning that I tested this on PowerShell 5.1.  I *believe* it will work as-is even on earlier versions, but even if it doesn't, it likely only requires minor changes to syntax.

```
$desired = @(
    @{ Key = 'editor.tabSize'; Value = 'EDITORTABSIZE'},
    @{ Key = 'workbench.startupEditor'; Value = 'WORKBENCHSTARTUPEDITOR'},
    @{ Key = 'missingKey'; Value = 'MISSINGKEY'}
)


$desired | ForEach-Object { 
    $key = $_.Key
    $value = $_.Value

    # Does key exist in the object
    if ($Json."${key}" -ne $null) {
        # Does key have the correct value
        if ($Json."${key}" -ne $value) {
            # Change keys value
            $Json."${key}" = $value
        }     
    }
    else {
        # Add key and value to object
        $Json | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $key -Value $value
    }
}
```

Comment: That work perfectly!!!!  Thanks.  Now that it's working I attempted to sort the object by key after the json object has been updated but it's not sorting.  `$json | sort-object -property $key` doesn't seem to work.